# How do I webscrabe image link tab

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am trying to webscrape the image tab so that I can get its link which I can use so I can go straight to images for the project I'm making.

The problem is that whenever I try to write "print(soup.find('a' , class_ = 'q qs')) it will give an output if none

The other problem the I come across is that the other tabs such as the Videos and news tab have the same tags but different links, so how would I differentiate between the two?

HTML for images link
I wish I could put a screenshot on here because this is hard to understand.

IMAGE TAB TAG

```
<div class="hdtb-mitem hdtb-imb" aria-selected="false" role="tab"><a class="q qs" href="/search?q=dogs&amp;safe=active&amp;client=safari&amp;rls=en&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=isch&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiqhrOi06zkAhVFVRUIHeBbATwQ_AUIESgB"><span class="HF9Klc ZYMsjf" style="height:16px;width:16px"><svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><path d="M14 13l4 5H6l4-4 1.79 1.78L14 13zm-6.01-2.99A2 2 0 0 0 8 6a2 2 0 0 0-.01 4.01zM22 5v14a3 3 0 0 1-3 2.99H5c-1.64 0-3-1.36-3-3V5c0-1.64 1.36-3 3-3h14c1.65 0 3 1.36 3 3zm-2.01 0a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v14a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h7v-.01h7a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V5z"></path></svg></span>Images</a></div>
```

HTML FOR IMAGES LINK

```
<a class="q qs" href="/search?q=dogs&amp;safe=active&amp;client=safari&amp;rls=en&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=isch&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiqhrOi06zkAhVFVRUIHeBbATwQ_AUIESgB"><span class="HF9Klc ZYMsjf" style="height:16px;width:16px"><svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><path d="M14 13l4 5H6l4-4 1.79 1.78L14 13zm-6.01-2.99A2 2 0 0 0 8 6a2 2 0 0 0-.01 4.01zM22 5v14a3 3 0 0 1-3 2.99H5c-1.64 0-3-1.36-3-3V5c0-1.64 1.36-3 3-3h14c1.65 0 3 1.36 3 3zm-2.01 0a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v14a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h7v-.01h7a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V5z"></path></svg></span>Images</a>
```

VIDEOS TAB TAG

```
<div class="hdtb-mitem hdtb-imb" aria-selected="false" role="tab"><a class="q qs" href="/search?q=dogs&amp;safe=active&amp;client=safari&amp;rls=en&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=vid&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiqhrOi06zkAhVFVRUIHeBbATwQ_AUIEigC"><span class="HF9Klc ZYMsjf" style="height:16px;width:16px"><svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10 16.5l6-4.5-6-4.5v9zM5 20h14a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V5a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v14a1 1 0 0 0 1 1zm14.5 2H5a3 3 0 0 1-3-3V4.4A2.4 2.4 0 0 1 4.4 2h15.2A2.4 2.4 0 0 1 22 4.4v15.1a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-2.5 2.5z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span>Videos</a></div>
```

HTML FOR VIDEOS LINK

```
<a class="q qs" href="/search? q=dogs&amp;safe=active&amp;client=safari&amp;rls=en&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=vid&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiqhrOi06zkAhVFVRUIHeBbATwQ_AUIEigC"><span class="HF9Klc ZYMsjf" style="height:16px;width:16px"><svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10 16.5l6-4.5-6-4.5v9zM5 20h14a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V5a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H5a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v14a1 1 0 0 0 1 1zm14.5 2H5a3 3 0 0 1-3-3V4.4A2.4 2.4 0 0 1 4.4 2h15.2A2.4 2.4 0 0 1 22 4.4v15.1a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-2.5 2.5z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></span>Videos</a>
```

You can see that the tags for the images and videos tabs are the same and I only one to retrieve one of them, how would I go about that, I only want the link to the images tab not the video tab.

Comment: if you indent your small html sections etc by 4 spaces they will be properly formatted. Or highlight and press Ctrl + K. Can you share the url you are using?  You can also use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html.

Comment: I fixed it you can now see the HTML

Comment: try soup.select_one('a:contains(Images)')['href']   ?

Answer (score 0):

If we see all the links we can to notice `tbm=vid` exist in the video link and `tbm=isch` in the image link.
We can use Python List Comprehension for scrape all links from the page and then use a filter for getting need data.

```
img_tag = [i for i in soup.find_all('a')]
```

This code return all `a` links.

```
img_tag = [i for i in soup.find_all('a') if 'tbm=isch' in i.get('href')]
```

Here I use filter in Python List Comprehension `if 'tbm=isch' in i.get('href')` and this code return `list` only with image links.

Anyway working code for you

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
img_tag = [i for i in soup.find_all('a') if 'tbm=isch' in i.get('href')]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.